# What are "Jamboree chess pairings"?

Tags: tournament, jamboree, pairing

Following on from [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/43349/algorithm-for-generating-jamboree-chess-pairings), what are "Jamboree chess pairings"? That is the first time I have heard of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather, a Jamboree tournament is a team tournament with fixed pairings (that is, they will not change based on results like a Swiss.) Unlike a typical team tournament, there is no one opponent that a team will face in a particular round.

For example, in a 2 round tournament with 3 teams, in round 1 team A might have their board 1 play against a player from team B, while their boards 2 and 3 play against players from team C.